# SWIFT dictionaries - Accessing a single value of a key with multiple values

Tags: swift, dictionary

To access the second value of the second key of the dictionary bellow:

> This question is not about getting any value of a key, but an specific value if this value is an array.

**For the following variable**

```
var dict2 = ["key1" : "value1", "key2" : [ "value1" , "value2" ]]
```

**This works (option 1)**

```
let value2 = dict2["key2"]?[1] as? String
println(value2!)
```

**But this do not (option2)**

```
let value2 = dict2["key2"][1]
```

Other users suggested the second option, but that does not work. I am wandering why.

Why should I cast the type? I imagine if the value was an Int I would have to cast it as an Int. But that assumes I know what type of value is in there and it exists. So why calling it as an optional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your dictionary has different types for values, it will probably have `AnyObject` as the type of the value.  You'll want to cast it to its type.  Also, dictionary accesses return optionals since the key might not be present in the dictionary, so you'll need to unwrap the value to access it.  Finally, your value is an array, so use an array index (`1` to access second item since array indices are `0` based). Here is a concrete example:

```
let dict = ["age" : 31, "names" : [ "Fred" , "Freddie" ]]

if let val = dict["names"]?[1] as? String {
    println(val)  // prints "Freddie"
}
```

Since an array index out of range will crash your program, to be completely safe you will want to do something like this:

```
if let array = dict["names"] as? [String] {
    if array.count > 1 {
        let name = array[1]
        println(name)
    }
}
```

This style protects you in the following ways:

1. If the key `"names"` isn't in your dictionary, the `if let` will do nothing instead of crashing.
2. If your value isn't an array of `String` as you thought it was, the `if let` will do nothing.
3. By checking the `array.count` first, this ensures that you won't get an array index out of bounds error.

---

To add a value to `"key2"` you'll need to first explicitly give your dictionary a type `[String: AnyObject]` because the type inferred by Swift is `NSDictionary` and that type is immutable, even if declared with `var`.

```
var dict2:[String: AnyObject] = ["key1" : "value1", "key2" : [ "value1" , "value2" ]]

if let value = dict2["key2"] as? [String] {
    dict2["key2"] = value + ["value3"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that the second key will have two elements you can access the second element with:

```
var value = dict[key2][1]
```

Comment: Here is the code I am trying.

`var dict2 = ["key1" : "value1", "key2" : [ "value1" , 45 ]]`

This works

`let value2 = dict2["key2"]?[1] as? Int
println(value2!)`

This don't

`let value3 = dict2["key2"][1]
println(value3)`

So not so sure about the reasons for the optionals and to cast it's type.